# Javascript Inertial side scroll on mouseover

Tags: javascript, scroll, slide, momentum

As I was looking through Killers Music html5 site, I wanted to do what they did with main navigation where when mouse is over to left or right, it will scroll infinite.

I have when through their javascript file, also inspected elements and one thing was for sure, they update left css property to scroll the background images.

I am not quite sure how to do that smoothly. I know I can use setTimeout to update the left but not sure what value I have to calculate to apply.
I am going to need someone's help or if there is any tutorial for it, it would be wonderful.

Please help.

Comment: Here is the web site in question: http://www.thekillersmusic.com

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [jQuery easing plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Easing).

Some demo are available here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html